# Sharepoint 2010 ribbon with Browse selected instead of View

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

Im customizing a DispForm page by adding some javascript in a content webpart at the bottom. Problem is the ribbon by default has selected "view" tab. I'd like to have "browse" selected instead. 
These 2 lines are not doing anything:

```
_ribbonStartInit("Ribbon.Read" , true , null ); 
_ribbonStartInit("Ribbon.Browse", true);
```

here:

```
var ribbon = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().get_ribbon()
```

get_ribbon() returns null /undefined.

Im calling the method using those lines with

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(setRibbonToBrowse1, "sp.ribbon.js" );
```

why is get_ribbon() undefined? why the 2 first lines aren't working. Alternative methods to achieve browse tab selected will also help.

Thanks a lot!